# ValueComparison null error when adding 'Last contribution is more than n days ago or is n days ago' as condition

Tags: wordpress, contributions, civirules, condition

I'm trying to set up a rule in CiviRules that will **send an e-mail n days after a contribution was made.**

When I try to save the condition parameters I get an error message.

**Can anyone confirm that this is a bug, or am I messing up something?**

Error log:

```
2020/02/06 13:20:26 [error] 8317#8317: *280630 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to civicrm_api3() must be of the type string, null given, called in .../shared/uploads/sites/5/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesConditions/Generic/ValueComparison.php on line 125 and defined in .../releases/20200204155448/web/app/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:84
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 .../shared/uploads/sites/5/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesConditions/Generic/ValueComparison.php(125): civicrm_api3(NULL, 'getfields', Array)
#1 .../shared/uploads/sites/5/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesConditions/Generic/ValueComparison.php(73): CRM_CivirulesConditions_Generic_ValueComparison->isDateField(NULL, NULL)
#2 .../shared/uploads/sites/5/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesConditions/Contribution/LastContribution.php(64): CRM_CivirulesConditions_Generic_ValueComparison->ge" while reading response header from upstream, client: [...], server: [...], request: "GET /wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcivirule%2Fform%2Frule&reset=1&action=update&id=2 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm-wordpress.sock:", host: [...], referrer: [...]/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcivirules%2Fform%2Frulesview&reset=1"
```

I reproduced the bug on the demo site:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might well be, but this is not the way I would specify the rule. This condition was for something pretty different, I do not recollect what exactly.

I would specify that the action is send email but the delay is xxxx number of days?

Like so:

[image]

Comment: Delay is a useful tool, however not in my case. My goal is to ask for a repeated contribution n days after the last contribution was made. Using delay would result in asking for a repeated contribution even if the contribution was already repeated within n days.

Comment: Sounds like you have to develop your own specific action then?